# How the index updates works for Solr and Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

I have an application that is using Event Sourcing and Command Query Responsiblity Seggragation Pattern. Development of the Command part is complete and I have to decide how should I implement the Query part.

My system deals with customer orders, so when event arrives for an order, that order processed with orderId and order payload. The thing is, in this form only whay to query the orders is over orderId so I can't ask a question like give me all the order in the system with status OPEN.

For this part I have to use the query part, my potential technology implementations for the query part, a classical solution like PostGre DB or more elegant way in my opinion Solr/Elasticsearch.

I have a basic knowledge/experience about Solr/Elasticsearch and I want to use this opurtunity to learn more but here comes my dilema. Some other department in our company is already working with Elasticsearch and a colleage from that deperatment told me, updates in elasticsearch is not a good idea, I didn't quite understand his argumentation, so I like to ask here what I am planning to do so you can tell me, it is a bad idea or Solr is better suited for it.

I am planning every status change for my order to send as an update for Elasticsearch, so it will look like the following.

| id |  | Status | Customer | Items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orderId1 | -> | order.SUBMITTED | order.Customer | order.Items |
| orderId1 | -> | order.CHANGED | order.Customer1 | order.Items |
| orderId1 | -> | order.PROCESSING | order.Customer1 | order.Items |
| orderId1 | -> | order.ON_DELIVERY | order.Customer1 | order.Items |
| orderId1 | -> | order.COMPLETE | order.Customer1 | order.Items |

As you see, I have to send several updates for orderId, to Elasticsearch/Solr.

So my colleague told me, Indexed Documents in Elasticsearch are immutables, when I send order.SUBMITTED Event to be indexed, it will create the document but order.CHANGED Event will not update the document but create another one. Now I can't quite judge the consequence of this, for my Business Case (I will ask orders of my Customer1 and I will see Status SUBMITTED and CHANGED, 2 records as query response) or operational (additional load and storage).

Did I understand correctly the behaviour of Eleasticsearch? If yes, will Solr behave any different?

If understood correctly an both will behave same, can I design anything differently that it would help reach my goals.

Finally I have no problem using PostGre for this solution, I just tough Elasticsearch or Solr would be a more natural choice for this problem. What do you think?

Thx for answers.

Comment: I would recommend you to design the Query component oriented on the questions you are planning to ask. For different questions (in terms of query, speed of answer needed, data volume), you might need different technologies, like: SOLR or ElasticSearch, but also Redis or Cassandra or Postgres. Indeed Solr and ElasticSearch have costly updates, but they are very fast when searching. Maybe you write a list of the queries + speed of response needed + data volume and decide based on that what technology to use for each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You colleague is partially correct, about the costly updates in Elasticsearch(ES) and updates being immutable, but it doesn't mean ES is not suitable for system with frequent updates, in fact due to its scalability and distributed nature its preferred choice and being used in high-throughput and low latency systems(including the search systems).
There are few misconception you have, and I would try to explain them.

1. Both ES and Solr are based on Lucene, and costly updates or immutable updates are the property of Lucene, so it doesn't matter whether you choose ES or Solr, you will underlying using Lucene and will have same update mechanism.
2. Updates are immutable it doesn't mean that your old status of Order will always be in the index, So for example initially your order status is `SUBMITTED` and later you update it to `CHANGED`, so even its immutable but when you query the order status, you will get the latest status(if [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html#refresh-api-desc) Happened on the index, default is 1 sec in ES), **Apart from permanent deletion of old documents(Happens during the merge process, explained in #3), ES marks old document as deleted(soft delete by updating a boolean flag delete, on updation of document), due to this during your search these soft deleted documents are not returned.**
3. ES periodically deletes the old document, so in your case `order` status `SUBMITTED` will be deleted from index during [merge process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html#index-modules-merge), so that old documents are deleted, and your index size doesn't grow.

**Also its very important to understand, that this immutable updates provides a huge benefit to improve the search/read performance as now these segments(which contains the documents in ES) can be used in multi-threading env as well as can be cached due to immutability reasons.**

Comment: Ok, first thx for your answer, but I have still some confusion about part 2 of your answer, now for docId: 1 V1:SUBMITTED and docId:1 V2:CHANGED I understand if I ask get GET /index_name/_doc/id1, I will get as an answer V2:CHANGED but  if I ask give me all Orders with status!=COMPLETE, I only get V2:CHANGED or V1:SUBMITTED and V2:CHANGED together?

Comment: @posthumecaver, very good question, i've updated my answer to make it more clear. so in your case it will return only one document with latest status ie CHANGED.

Comment: Ok, that answers all my questions, I will give it a go with ES fo rmy Query component. But just for curiosity, you say when V2 is there V1 will be marked as 'Soft Delete', is there way  to ask for old versions, like for seeing version history?

Comment: @posthumecaver but you can know the current version of your document using GET API, where ES returns the `_version` which is incremental starting from 1. for ex if your document id is 1 then just inspect the output of GET `<your-index>/_doc/1`